# CSS equivalent for QML's "elide: Text.ElideMiddle"

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, qml

QML `Text` has got a property named [`elide`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#elide-prop), which is used to elide some part of a text. Its CSS equivalent is [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). One possible value for `elide` is `Text.ElideMiddle`, used to elide the text in the middle. I have searched such a value for `text-overflow` but I have not found it yet. It is possible to elide at the left and at the right in CSS (with `text-overflow: ellipsis ellipsis;` on Firefox only), but I want the opposite. I want something like "*1 2 3 … 7 8 9*" instead of "*… 4 5 6 …*".

So my question is simple: **How to simulate QML's `elide: Text.ElideMiddle` in CSS?** I am running short of ideas about this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible with CSS.

Comment: I think that it is not possible only with a single CSS property (or a combination of them) too. I am rather looking for a way to mimic it, using also HTML (using several elements if required) and JS if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simulation with css is possible, but I would do it in back-end (php, offline js) as that is the only way to get it right - just replacement the middle of the string with ellipsis.
I assume, that you can predict the length of this string. If not, the code will be longer by length count and condition.
With css you can cut string with less reasonable effect, imitation is possible with `flex` and repetition of the string. If you can't predict length of the string - back-end handling will be necessary and using css seems to be just redundancy.
<sup>... I can't force a snippet to read the function - it will be with inline js...</sup>

```js
function elip(i,str){
  var x = str.replace(str.slice(i,-i),' ... ');
  document.write(x);}
```

```css
/*    for snippet only    */
section{ background: #014; color: #fff; padding: 20px; margin: 20px auto}
p{ min-width: 5em; white-space: nowrap; display: flex; }
span{ background: #fff; color: #014; padding: 5px}
hr{ background: 0; border: 0}

/*    imitation    */
p{ white-space: nowrap; display: flex}
span{ display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; min-width: 1em}

.short{ width: 5em}
.mid{ width: 20em}
#css span{ max-width: 50%}
#css span:first-child{ display: flex; justify-content: flex-start}
#css span:last-child{ display: flex; justify-content: flex-end}
#css:hover span:nth-child(2){ background: #abc}

#css .triple span:nth-child(2){ color: transparent; width: 1em}
#css .triple span:nth-child(2)::before{ content: ' ... '; color: initial}
```

```html
<section><h1>js</h1>
i=3 <hr>
<span><script>var i=3; var str='Beethoven'; document.write(str.replace(str.slice(i,-i),' ... '));</script></span>
<hr>  i = 20; - more than string length - too much  <hr>
<span><script>var i=20; var str='Beethoven'; document.write(str.replace(str.slice(i,-i),' ... '));</script></span>
<hr>  i = 20  <hr>
<span><script>var i=20; var str='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'; document.write(str.replace(str.slice(i,-i),' ... '));</script></span></section>

<section id="css"><h1>css</h1>    <h3>string - ellipsis - string</h3>
5em<p class="short">
<span>Beethoven</span><span>...</span><span>Beethoven</span></p>
20em<p class="mid">
<span>Beethoven</span><span>...</span><span>Beethoven</span></p>
20em<p class="mid">
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
<span>...</span>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></p>

<h3>lazy - triple string</h3>
5em<p class="short triple">
<span>Beethoven</span><span>Beethoven</span><span>Beethoven</span></p>
20em<p class="mid triple">
<span>Beethoven</span><span>Beethoven</span><span>Beethoven</span></p>
20em<p class="mid triple">
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></p>
</section>
```